# AWS Kubernetes Exposed Service Timeout Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, gcloud

I got an issue when I try to access an exposed `kubernetes` service through browser. Below is my Environment.

created two `ubuntu` EC2 instances(with all ports open in security group) and installed all kubernetes related tools like kubectl, kubeadm, docker, calico network.

created `nginx` pod, scaled it to 3 and exposed it with type **LoadBalancer**. When I curl from master or worker node to the exposed nginx it works fine(with public or private ip). But it does not work if i curl from outside. The request is timed out. I tried to delete service and expose it again with NodePort. But still I could not access from outside. I ensured the security group allows ingress. Is there a way to debug why it cannot be accessed from outside or I am missing something

I am not running `cloud controller manager` but `kube-controller-manager`. Will this be an issue.?

below is the output of all kubernetes components

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-29-98:~$ kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       pod/nginx-6f858d4d45-2wtlh                     1/1       Running   0          51m
default       pod/nginx-6f858d4d45-5dkws                     1/1       Running   0          51m
default       pod/nginx-6f858d4d45-h9cwg                     1/1       Running   0          51m
kube-system   pod/calico-etcd-82xkv                          1/1       Running   1          18h
kube-system   pod/calico-kube-controllers-74b888b647-prr2q   1/1       Running   1          18h
kube-system   pod/calico-node-kbckk                          2/2       Running   4          17h
kube-system   pod/calico-node-n5zhr                          2/2       Running   3          18h
kube-system   pod/coredns-78fcdf6894-qjhlq                   1/1       Running   1          18h
kube-system   pod/coredns-78fcdf6894-sm7c9                   1/1       Running   1          18h
kube-system   pod/etcd-ip-172-31-29-98                       1/1       Running   1          18h
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-29-98             1/1       Running   1          18h
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-29-98    1/1       Running   1          18h
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-jxg88                           1/1       Running   1          18h
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-knx59                           1/1       Running   1          17h
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-29-98             1/1       Running   1          18h

NAMESPACE     NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
default       service/kubernetes    ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP         18h
default       service/nginx         LoadBalancer   10.99.144.149   <pending>     80:31808/TCP    45m
kube-system   service/calico-etcd   ClusterIP      10.96.232.136   <none>        6666/TCP        18h
kube-system   service/kube-dns      ClusterIP      10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   18h

NAMESPACE     NAME                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                     AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/calico-etcd   1         1         1         1            1           node-role.kubernetes.io/master=   18h
kube-system   daemonset.apps/calico-node   2         2         2         2            2           <none>                            18h
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy    2         2         2         2            2           beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64     18h

NAMESPACE     NAME                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default       deployment.apps/nginx                      3         3         3            3           51m
kube-system   deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers    1         1         1            1           18h
kube-system   deployment.apps/calico-policy-controller   0         0         0            0           18h
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns                    2         2         2            2           18h

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
default       replicaset.apps/nginx-6f858d4d45                      3         3         3         51m
kube-system   replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-74b888b647    1         1         1         18h
kube-system   replicaset.apps/calico-policy-controller-55b469c8fd   0         0         0         18h
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-78fcdf6894                    2         2         2         18h
```

**Edit 1:**
Tried to do the same in `GCloud`. It is same in `GCloud` too. The `nginx` Service is accessible through private/public ip inside the nodes. But when I curl from outside, it does not work. I spin up a simply python server in one of the node and I am able to access the python server from outside. But only the services exposed through `kubernetes` are not curl-able from outside.

I think I am missing some fundamental understanding about `kubernetes` networking(especially in cloud). Can I get any help from experts?

Comment: also saw this similar Question. But no answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025256/kubernetes-exposed-service-on-ec2-not-accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internet firewall on my network was blocking the access to specific ports. There was no issues with the Cloud Provider Firewall or Instance Firewall.

Answer (score 1):

How did you create your cluster?  `kubeadm`?  You need some custom configs for your cluster to run with AWS.  For example your `kube-controller-manager` and `kube-apiserver` need to have the option `--cloud-provider=aws`. Same for all your kubelets.

I'd recommend using [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) if you don't want to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks Rico. I wanted to learn `kubernetes` cluster setup on my own instead of leaving it to `kops`, I did all those steps manually by creating 2 ec2 instances and running `kubeadm init` on master and `kubeadm join ...` on worker. also applied `calico` manifest yaml before joining the worker.

now I got 2 questions. how will give `cloud provider = aws` with kubeadm.? and If I do this will it create a `ELB` instead of Normal Load balancer(like the one in minikube).?

I will do my research on this.